# Autocopy TypeScript and LESS

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

I am developing a SharePoint 2013 App with Visual Studio 2013. My problem is, I use TypeScript instead of JavaScript and LESS instead of CSS. When I change the `*.ts` and `*.less` files they are not copied to the SharePoint, but when I edit the generated `*.js` and `*.css` files they get copied just perfectly fine.

Is it possible to auto copy the generated files?

PS: I have CKSDev installed, if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have js and css files copied to SharePoint after editing the ts and less files then you can use the Visual Studio Extension SPFastDeploy to do that.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e03d0f5-f931-4125-a5d1-7c1529554fbd

Comment: I just get a 401 from the SharePoint if I try it with it :(

Comment: The extension requires that the SharePoint client libraries be installed on your dev computer.

Comment: Maybe I have the wrong ones installed, but it still doesn't work, might it be, because my dev computer and SharePointserver are different machines and I am not working in a domain context?

Comment: That must be it. The extension will prompt for credentials if you are deploying to O365 but not if you are cross domain. Sorry. I will look into adding that in the next version. I am assuming that VS is prompting you when you deploy to SharePoint?

Comment: Yeah it does. But like I said, I am not developing in O365 :/ Is the extension open source? If yes I could maybe check myself :)

Comment: Version 3.5.1 now supports cross domain deployment. You will now be prompted. Check it out and let me know.